# Verify username and a salted password

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc, passwords

I have a application that usues JDBC Jquery and MYSQL that lists a table with quotes and the user can add quotes.

i have a loggin page where i check the input of username and compare it with something that exits in the database. like this and it works fine

```
public Boolean findByUsername(String username) throws SQLException {

        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {

            conn = Database.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, username);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return true;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But when i want to compare the password i get the problem with that i salt the password with PBKDF2 it generates some random characters like this 
1000:485b5808b4786d6aa6e5360ad157945ee927d85e49e96312:60d76b0ef1b742cfa462d84eb7fd7c37eb361717179c0a45. When i want to compare the passwordinput with something in the database i use this method.

```
public Boolean findByPassword(String password) throws SQLException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PasswordHash p = new PasswordHash();
        String hash = p.createHash(password);
        try {

            conn = Database.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE passwd = ?";
System.out.println("password: " +password);
System.out.println("hashpassword " +hash);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, hash);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                if(p.validatePassword(password, hash)){ 
                    return true;

                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I uses this class to hash the password

```
public class PasswordHash {
    public final String PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";

    // The following constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
    public final int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
    public final int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
    public final int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

    public final int ITERATION_INDEX = 0;
    public final int SALT_INDEX = 1;
    public final int PBKDF2_INDEX = 2;

    /**
     * Returns a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the password to hash
     * @return a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password
     */
    public String createHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        return createHash(password.toCharArray());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the password to hash
     * @return a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password
     */
    public String createHash(char[] password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        // Generate a random salt
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        // Hash the password
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
        // format iterations:salt:hash
        return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + toHex(salt) + ":" + toHex(hash);
    }

    /**
     * Validates a password using a hash.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the password to check
     * @param correctHash
     *            the hash of the valid password
     * @return true if the password is correct, false if not
     */
    public boolean validatePassword(String password, String correctHash)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        return validatePassword(password.toCharArray(), correctHash);
    }

    /**
     * Validates a password using a hash.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the password to check
     * @param correctHash
     *            the hash of the valid password
     * @return true if the password is correct, false if not
     */
    public boolean validatePassword(char[] password, String correctHash)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        // Decode the hash into its parameters
        String[] params = correctHash.split(":");
        int iterations = Integer.parseInt(params[ITERATION_INDEX]);
        byte[] salt = fromHex(params[SALT_INDEX]);
        byte[] hash = fromHex(params[PBKDF2_INDEX]);
        // Compute the hash of the provided password, using the same salt,
        // iteration count, and hash length
        byte[] testHash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hash.length);
        // Compare the hashes in constant time. The password is correct if
        // both hashes match.
        return slowEquals(hash, testHash);
    }

    /**
     * Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison method
     * is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from an on-line
     * system using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
     * 
     * @param a
     *            the first byte array
     * @param b
     *            the second byte array
     * @return true if both byte arrays are the same, false if not
     */
    private boolean slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
            diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
        return diff == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the PBKDF2 hash of a password.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the password to hash.
     * @param salt
     *            the salt
     * @param iterations
     *            the iteration count (slowness factor)
     * @param bytes
     *            the length of the hash to compute in bytes
     * @return the PBDKF2 hash of the password
     */
    private byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations,
            int bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
        return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a string of hexadecimal characters into a byte array.
     *
     * @param hex
     *            the hex string
     * @return the hex string decoded into a byte array
     */
    private byte[] fromHex(String hex) {
        byte[] binary = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            binary[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(
                    hex.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
        }
        return binary;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a byte array into a hexadecimal string.
     *
     * @param array
     *            the byte array to convert
     * @return a length*2 character string encoding the byte array
     */
    private String toHex(byte[] array) {
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
        String hex = bi.toString(16);
        int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
        if (paddingLength > 0)
            return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
        else
            return hex;
    }

    /**
     * Tests the basic functionality of the PasswordHash class
     *
     * @param args
     *            ignored
     */

}
```

i call the metod here

```
@POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String LogInUser(String username, String password)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            SQLException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User theuser = gson.fromJson(username, User.class);
        if (!u.findByUsername(theuser.getUsername())
                && u.findByPassword(theuser.getPasswd())) {
            return theuser.getUsername();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

how do i compare the passwordinput  with something that exits in the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query the database in your `findByUsername` method using `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?`. Result of that query should return the password hash as well. So just take the password hash from this query, and call `validatePassword`.

Forget your `findByPassword` method. It won't work. Besides it being completely wrong. (it would return true if any of the users stored in database had the password provided)

Some hints on storing passwords in SQL (or actually any database, or rather any storage):

- Always store the password hashed by **strong hash**. (You do that, but this should be repeated anytime anyone is talking about storing passwords)
- Always **salt the hashes**. (you do that as well, but same as above)

  - And please make sure your **salts are random**.
- Always **query by** username or whatever your **unique** identificator is.
- Have a unique key on this identificator.
- Never use any column which could contain duplicates to find the user record.

  - That means **never query by password** (or hash), as well.
- **Never use the password in your query.** Never in cleartext.

  - Better, try avoiding hashes in the SELECTs.
- Use multiround algorithms. But with care.

  - Do not implement the algorithm yourself, unless you know what you are doing.
  - Keep the number of rounds reasonable. Hashing the password for 100ms may get you DoSed easily.
  - Do not do things like `for(int i=0;i<rounds;i++) md5(previous_hash)`. It may, and will, compromise the hash.
- **Never implement hashes yourself.** (Unless of course you very well know what you are doing)
- **Do not combine hashes.**

  - `md5(sha256(sha512(password)))` might seem as a good idea at first, but trust me, it is not.
- **Always store the password hashed. Always use strong hash. Always salt the hash with a random salt.**

(if anyone has a tip on missing hint, I'll be happy to add ...)

Comment: BCrypt and PBKDF2 _are_ multi-round algorithms, do you mean that we should not use them? Actually for passwords one should _explicitly_ choose slow hash functions with a cost factor.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I did not say "do not use them". All I am saying is, be careful. If implemented wrong you decrease the security and introduce bottleneck, especially if people blow the number of rounds through the roof. (seen that happen, and trust me, working with system, where  password gets hashed about 100ms is no pleasant experience) Edited the answer. Hope its more clear.

Comment: Yes, now it is well understandable. Using 50ms per password is often a good target, a DoS attack you have to counter otherwise, the only possibility for an attack is the registration form anyway.

Comment: I agree that 50ms is better than 100ms+, and I am no cryptography/security expert, so in no way I want to argue. But if you are after high password security, rather switch away from PBKDF2, which is rather easy to paralellize (on GPU/FPGA) to something like bcrypt/scrypt, which have way lower CPU->GPU scaling factor. I acknowledge this approach has drawbacks as well ...